# textarea resize parent div container

Tags: css, html, textarea

How can I make a div grow in height when a text-area is resized in html?

I have the following code

```html
       <div class="reply">
                <p>Please enter your reply:</p>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit reply"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
```

However when the user resizes, the text-area goes out of its container, how can I make the height of the parent div grow with the size of the text area?

Picture of problem

[image]

Comment: Please post some CSS.  The problem could be as simple as `.reply` having a fixed height, hard to tell without more details.

Answer (score 15):

Your `.reply div` will be resized automatically if you do not give fixed height.
if you want to resize only vertically than try using -

```
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jsz2nyb/)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize